# Пересылка нескольких параметров в ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Все та же форма регистрации. Есть два поля - для пароля и повторноо ввода пароля(проверка).

```
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="pass1" id="pass1" value="">
<div id="results6"></div>
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="pass2" id="pass2" value="">
<div id="results7"></div>
```

(в div'ax выводится результат)

Скрипт:

```
$("#pass1").blur(function() {
    var searchString = $("#pass1").val();
    var data         = 'pass1=' + searchString;

    if (searchString) {
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "funk/check.php",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function(html) { 
                $("#results6").html("<img src='imgs/iLOAD.png' width='24px' height='24px'/>"); 
            },
            success: function(html) { 
            $("#results6").empty();
                $("#results6").show();
                $("#results6").append(html);
            }
        });    
    }
    return false;
});
```

Посылает введенное в первое поле информацию в php функцию и принимает ответ в соответствующий div.

Как написать скрипт для второго поля, чтобы передавалось значение и первого и второго поля? В функции они будут сверяться.

Comment: Спасибо!
Я на самом деле примерно так и сделал, но вкралась синтаксическая ошибка =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var data = 'pass1=' + $('#pass1').val() + '&pass2=' + $('#pass2').val();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
    pass1: $('#pass1').val(),
    pass2: $('#pass2').val()
}
```